Почему переменная arsum, объявленная через let и ниже определения sum_fu(val), видна внутри sum_fu, как если бы я объявил ее через var?
Подскажите, почему я использую внутри функции sum_fu переменную arsum, но она объявлена позже, чем определение функции sum_fu и вдобавок arsum я объявляю через let, значит поднятия наверх нет (как если бы было через var) , тем не менее почему то это работает. Не понимаю, почему.
function sum_fu(val) {
arsum = arsum + val;
}

let arsum = 0;

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];

arr1.forEach( sum_fu );

console.log(arsum);


Особенность области видимости... https://learn.javascript.ru/closure

Лексическое окружение «собирается» до выполнения кода, так что JS знает что области видимости есть переменная arsum даже когда функция объявлена до переменной. Вы запускаете функцию после инициализации переменной поэтому ошибки не возникает.

Понял, спасибо.

внутри функции на первом месте есть внутреннее окружение переменных. А также на втором месте - внешнее. Если во внешнем окружении существует переменная arsum то функция будет работать. А если вызовете эту функцию в другом месте, в котором нет данной переменной - то будет ошибка.

Интересно это работает, да. Не как в С++.

@AlexGlebe, вы описали вариант динамического поиска, когда переменные ищутся вверх по стеку текущего вызова. Но в JavaScript список окружений в котором отыскивается символ фиксирован, определяется порядком пространств имен в месте определения функции.

Когда вы вызываете arr1.forEach( sum_fu );, то оба определения уже обработаны: sum_fu и arsum. Чтобы получить ошибку перенесите вызов arr1.forEach( sum_fu ); до определения arsum:


function sum_fu(val) {
arsum = arsum + val;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
arr1.forEach( sum_fu );

let arsum = 0;



Ошибка формулируется как

"message": "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'arsum' before initialization"

Декларация переменной arsum доступна везде в области видимости, и компилятор про неё уже знает. Но он также знает, что мы пытаемся с ней работать до того как она получила значение.
Поднятие вверх здесь не при чём. Функция sum_fu компилируется с обращением к глобальному символу arsum. Наличие самого символа во время компиляции не нужно. Во время исполнения sum_fu символ отыскиваются в объемлющей области видимости, а в этот момент он уже определён (это про ваш оригинальный код).
Чтобы ощутить "поднятие" переменной к ней нужно обратится из кода в той же области видимости. Обратите внимание что "поднимается" только сама декларация (имя становится видимо), присвоение значения остаётся на месте:


console.log(a);
var a = 'A';
console.log(a);



Тот же код с let даёт ошибку:


console.log(a);
let a = 'A';
console.log(a);




Спасибо большое!

"поднимается" только сама декларация (имя становится видимо), присвоение значения остаётся на месте" про это читал в книгах. Это может давать трудноуловимые ошибки.

@Timur123, это повод не использовать var и function. Только const, let и стрелочные функции.
